# How can I remove a newline character in a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I use **BeautifulSoup** to extract a website and I got a the text need. The problem is it has **"\n"** character in the text which I need to remove.

sample output text:

> \nI went to an advance screening of this movie thinking I was about
>   to\nembark on 120 minutes of cheezy lines, mindless plot, and the kind
>   of\nnauseous acting that made "The Postman" one of the most
>   malignant\ndisplays of cinematic blundering of our time. But I was
>   shocked.\nShocked to find a film starring Costner that appealed to the
>   soul of\nthe audience. Shocked that Ashton Kutcher could act in such a
>   serious\nrole. Shocked that a film starring both actually engaged and
>   captured\nmy own emotions. Not since 'Robin Hood' have I seen this
>   Costner: full\nof depth and complex emotion. Kutcher seems to have
>   tweaked the serious\nacting he played with in "Butterfly Effect".
>   These two actors came into\nthis film with a serious, focused attitude
>   that shone through in what I\nthought was one of the best films I've
>   seen this year. No, its not an\nOscar worthy movie. It's not an epic,
>   or a profound social commentary\nfilm. Rather, its a story about a
>   simple topic, illuminated in a way\nthat brings that audience to a
>   higher level of empathy than thought\npossible. That's what I think
>   good film-making is and I for one am\nthroughly impressed by this
>   work. Bravo!\n

I tried the below methods to remove the new line.

method 1 - regex

```
x = review_text.get_text()
y = re.sub(r'(\n)','',x)
```

method 2 - rstrip

```
x = review_text.get_text()
x.rstrip()
```

Neither of this methods are working for me.

When I use split

```
x = review_text.get_text()
print(x.split("\n"),"\n\n")
```

The output is as follows

> ['\nI went to an advance screening of this movie thinking I was about
>   to\nembark on 120 minutes of cheezy lines, mindless plot, and the
>   kind of\nnauseous acting that made "The Postman" one of the most
>   malignant\ndisplays of cinematic blundering of our time. But I was
>   shocked.\nShocked to find a film starring Costner that appealed to
>   the soul of\nthe audience. Shocked that Ashton Kutcher could act in
>   such a serious\nrole. Shocked that a film starring both actually
>   engaged and captured\nmy own emotions. Not since \'Robin Hood\' have
>   I seen this Costner: full\nof depth and complex emotion. Kutcher
>   seems to have tweaked the serious\nacting he played with in
>   "Butterfly Effect". These two actors came into\nthis film with a
>   serious, focused attitude that shone through in what I\nthought was
>   one of the best films I\'ve seen this year. No, its not an\nOscar
>   worthy movie. It\'s not an epic, or a profound social
>   commentary\nfilm. Rather, its a story about a simple topic,
>   illuminated in a way\nthat brings that audience to a higher level of
>   empathy than thought\npossible. That\'s what I think good film-making
>   is and I for one am\nthroughly impressed by this work. Bravo!\n']

what should I do to remove the new lines from the text.

Thank you.

Comment: `x.replace('\n', ' ')` ?

Comment: If `x` is a string, `re.sub` works for me (the other two methods are incorrect.) Can you confirm that `x` is a string? What does `type(x)` return?

Comment: Hint: There's a difference between the single character `'\n'` and the string `"\\n"` that has two characters: the first being a backslash, and the second being `'n'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it's `'\n'` character and not `'\\n'` two character sequence? If it's '\n', `x.rstrip()` should work. Otherwise, try `x.replace('\\n','')`

Answer (score 3):

If s is, a string such as:

```
\nNo, its not an\nOscar worthy movie. It's not an epic, or a profound social commentary\nfilm. Rather, its a story about a simple topic, illuminated in a way\nthat brings that audience to a higher level of empathy than thought\npossible. That's what I think good film-making is and I for one am\nthroughly impressed by this work. Bravo!\n
```

then s.strip() will remove trailing and leading whitespace, which includes newlines:

```
 No, its not an\nOscar worthy movie. It's not an epic, or a profound social commentary\nfilm. Rather, its a story about a simple topic, illuminated in a way\nthat brings that audience to a higher level of empathy than thought\npossible. That's what I think good film-making is and I for one am\nthroughly impressed by this work. Bravo!
```

To remove all the other \n, replace them with " " for a space or "" to remove completely

```
s.replace("\n", " ").strip()

No, its not an Oscar worthy movie. It's not an epic, or a profound social commentary film. Rather, its a story about a simple topic, illuminated in a way that brings that audience to a higher level of empathy than thought possible. That's what I think good film-making is and I for one am throughly impressed by this work. Bravo!
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `x=x.replace("\n", "")` to take out the newline.